# Insert image in html only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is in the JS file

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('appController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('auto_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;         
        });
    }]);

})();
```

This is the JSON

```
{
    "question" : "Saturn is the ______ planet from the Sun.",
    "image" : "images/category/1.jpg",
    "answers" : [
        {"id" : 0, "text" : "Fourth" },
        {"id" : 1, "text" : "Sixth" },
        {"id" : 2, "text" : "Second" },
        {"id" : 3, "text" : "Eight" }           
    ],
    "correct" : 1
}
```

And this is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="appController">
    <div ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions  " >
        <h2 class="txt" >{{myQuestion.question}}</h2>
        <div ng-repeat="answer in myQuestions[$index].answers">
            <p>{{answer.text}}</p>
            <img ng-src="{{myQuestion.image}}" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/quiz_test.js"></script>
</html>
```

In this situation the image shows up 3 times on the page. How to make the image show up only once?

Comment: you should move the `img` tag with `{{myQuestion.image}}` out of the inner `ng-repeat`.

Comment: One thing I will note as well is that in your inner ng-repeat, you are using myQuestions[$index], which is the exact same thing as the current myQuestion object in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<img ng-src="{{myQuestion.image}}" >` below the the closing `</div>` under its current position. It's shown multiple times because it's caught up in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can either place the image outside the inner ng-repeat, or you can conditionally display it by $index.

```
<div ng-repeat="myQuestion in myQuestions">
...
  <div ng-repeat="answer in myQuestion.answers">
       <p>{{answer.text}}</p>
       <img ng-src="{{myQuestion.image}}" ng-if="$index == 0"/>
   </div>
</div>
```